# How do I move mesh up and down at weird angle?

Tags: mesh, vertices, faces, edges, axis

How do I move the knuckle's up on my model while matching the odd angle its at? Just in case in the future if I ever encounter this problem again and not only do I need to move it up but down too.[image]

Comment: keep these faces selected and in the Transform Orientations panel (center top of your 3D view), select the Normal orientation

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two options here.

**OPTION 1: NORMAL ORIENTATION**
The first one has already been answered in the comments by moonboots, which is to switch your transform orientation to "normal", which Blender will take its best guess depending on the way your object is shaped (affecting which directions the normals point in).

Here is a generic Ico Sphere I stretched out and rotated at a random angle. Lets say I want to move it similarly to your knuckle example.
[image]

With any of your move/rotate/scale tools active, click on this dropdown box (if you haven't touched anything beforehand, this should say "Default")
[image]

In the dropdown menu, look for "normal" and after you click that...
[image]

Your gizmo should angle itself according to the object's normals.
[image]

**OPTION 2: PARENTING TO A CUSTOM OBJECT**
If the selected object is too complex, then the above method may not give you the angle you want, or maybe you have a specific angle in mind. Lets say I want to keep this monkey head just the way it is, but I want to move it in the same diagonal direction as before:
[image]

In that case, I'll add a simple cube (although an empty would work just as well)...
[image]

...and rotate it to the exact angle that I want.
[image]

After that, all you have to do is parent the monkey to the cube you just made (For this example I'll assume you already know how to parent objects). With your move tool's orientation set to "Normal", your gizmo will orient itself the way the cube is.
[image]

If you move the cube, the monkey will move in the same direction. Once the monkey is in place, simply unparent the two objects and delete the cube.

**IMPORTANT DISTINCTION**
In the above images I showed you only change the selected tool (move/scale/rotation), which will change if you switch to a different tool, meaning you may change your Scale tool to "normal", but your Move and Rotation tools will still be set to "Default" when you switch to them.

In the top center of the screen is a similar box that will change all tools **that have their orientation set to "Default"**. If you have changed an orientation setting for one of your tools, that will take priority instead.
[image]

Comment: I notice you said "edit" mode but most of the images say object mode.

Comment: You're absolutely right, and that would be an error on my part. I'll edit the post to reflect that. The only requirement I believe is that you just need any of the move/scale/rotate tools active to be able to change the gizmo orientation.